# What is the difference between owned and pwned?

Tags: meaning

People have been using pwned on a lot of youtube videos and i have NO clue what that even means?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Owned is standard English eg Bob owned a nice car (past tense)

pwned is hacker slang originally used in the context of successfully accessing a system eg Bob totally pwned  that NASA server. It now (when used by civilians) has a general sense of getting one over on some one quite often by less than legal means.

Comment: On Internet, you can use either for the same meaning.

Comment: @Archa I'm pretty sure the Washington Post website (which is part of then internet) you could not write 'pwned' in all the places you might use 'owned'.

Comment: @Archa actually you can not pwned has a quite different emphasis implying a triumphant or dominating element eg Chile pwned Spain 5-1

Answer (score 3):

As much as I dislike using Wikipedia as a source...

> Etymology
>
> The word pwn most likely came about as a common typo of the word own
>   because the "p" and "o" keys are adjacent on a standard English
>   keyboard.[6][7]

My gut feeling tells me that this fits the bill

Comment: Wish I could speak English like you :)

Comment: I appreciate the compliment, but I fear the purpose of the site prohibits self-inflation of ego. The commentary and answers should be for learning purposes, in the broadest sense, so let's focus on making sure we all improve our English one day at a time, shall we?

Answer (score -1):

In the context of the internet and video games, they are similar. 
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwn)

Comment: They don't mean the same. Nobody 'pwns' a house, pet or piece of art.

Comment: It's in the internet context, but of course, no one pwns a house.